# Ctrl and super keys not working in anydesk in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, anydesk

I am the guy who use anydesk very frequently to connect remote desktops but i am not able to use ctrl and super key shortcuts.
Do we have any solution for it?

Comment: https://support.anydesk.com/Keyboard